# Why does empty Bitbucket repo "contain work" that I "do not have locally"?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a project on my system that I want to store on Bitbucket. I created the empty project on Bitbucket (with a Readme), and then did the following commands in the root of my project:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin <path-to-repo>
git push -u origin --all
```

I got these commands from [this link](https://ommune.com/kb/pushing-a-new-project-directory-to-bitbucket-repository/)

It gave me the error that `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally`. It suggests doing `git pull` but I'm worried that if I do that it will erase the work I have locally.

What should I do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It gave me the error that `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally`. It suggests doing `git pull`. What should I do here?

Do what it says. `git pull`.

> I'm worried that if I do that it will erase the work I have locally.

Well, stop worrying. This is git. Once committed, nothing is ever, ever lost.

> Why does empty Bitbucket repo “contain work” that I “do not have locally”?

Well, you told us the answer to that yourself: It isn’t empty! “With a Readme,” you said. Do you have the Readme locally? No, you don’t. So the Bitbucket repo contains work you do not have locally.

---

**EDIT** So the problem with the instructions you tried to follow is that those instructions assume your Bitbucket repo is empty — and we have already established that it isn't. Well, in `git push -u`, the point of the `u` is to associate your `master` branch with Bitbucket's `master` branch. You need to do that in order to push or pull, and you are allowed to do it the first time you push. Okay, but `git push -u` only works if you *can* push. But you *can't* push because you have not pulled the Readme. And you can't pull the Readme because `git push -u` didn't succeed! Catch-22!!

The solution is to intervene manually by saying (while on `master`):

```
git branch -u origin/master
```

Now you have formed the necessary association, and so you can just `git pull` and `git push` plain and simple and all will be well.

Comment: Once I pull, how does that affect my staging area etc? In order to push, will I have to `git add` etc again?

Comment: I did `git pull`, then `git push -u origin --all`, and got the message "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote change (e.g. 'git pull ...')  before pushing again"

Comment: `git status` says `On branch master. Nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: That's all it says, yes. I've gone back through the commands I entered and can't find anything I did that I haven't shared.

Comment: @gkeenley Try `git pull` again?

Comment: I did `git pull` again, then `git push`, and it says `fatal: the current branch master has no upstream branch. To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use git push --set-upstream origin master`. Should I do `git push -u origin --all` again?

Comment: @gkeenley Yes, do that

Comment: @wjandrea I undid and re-did everything, but replaced `git push -u origin --all` with `git push origin master` and it worked fine. If you can figure out why that made a difference, I'll get you a present.